# Open CHM file only when it is not opened already

Tags: c++, mfc, chm

I need to open a chm file from my MFC dialog only when it is not opened. If the page is already opened, need to show the same window.
Now I am using ShellExecuteW(NULL, L"open", chmPath, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL) and executed from a button click. It is working fine but I click again this button it will open a new page. I need to show the same page while it is already in open state.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at HTML Help API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms670172%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You should use the HtmlHelp() API. Best (old) stuff is:

http://www.smountain.com/m_ProgrammingHelp.htm

or PDF directly:
http://www.smountain.com/resource/CPPHTMLHelp.pdf

or context-sensitive help from Microsoft too:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/191118